# Як вірно буде написати "мускатний цвіт" один словом, мацИс чи мацІс, (мИс чи мЕс)?

Tags: from-english, терміни, росіянізм, запозичені-слова

Російською: [Мацис](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%81)

Скоріше за всього це транслітерація з macis.

Comment: Будь ласка, додайте до питання свої міркування з приводу того, як треба транслітерувати це слово. На цьому сайті заохочуються питання, які користувач ставить вже після свого особистого, хоча б мінімального дослідження. Після того, як ви це зробите, зніму свій мінус і поставлю плюс. Зауважу, що транслітерація російською не є дослідженням, бо не порівнює досвід декількох слов'янських мов, а просто дивиться на одну з них.

Answer (score 3):

Для вирішення цього питання досить правила дев'ятки. МацИс.

Правопис, параграф 90, пункт 5, підпункт "в":

> `И` пишеться:
>   В загальних назвах після приголосних `д`, `т`, `з`, `с`, `ц`, `ж` (`дж`), `ч`, `ш`, `р` перед наступним приголосним: *ди́зель, дина́мо, дипло́м, дире́ктор, мето́дика; інститу́т, матема́тика, сти́мул, тексти́ль, тип; зиґза́ґ, пози́ція, фізи́чний; маркси́зм, силуе́т, систе́ма; цисте́рна, ци́фра; жирандо́ль, режи́м, джигі́т, джи́нси; речитати́в, чичеро́не; ши́рма, шифр; брига́да, риф, фа́брика*.

Щодо росіянізмів, не знаю, де ви його тут вбачаєте, а ось "вірно" в запитанні це якраз він і є.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian.SE! Цей сайт — не форум і не чат-борд, тому ми заохочуємо відповіді, які базуються на дослідженнях, а не на особистих думках. Якщо ви згадуєте правило девʼятки, то робіть посилання і надавайте релевантні цитати. Будь ласка, перегляньте [faq], щоб дізнатися більше.